# Recording a customer's shopping cart as an order 2.0

Tags: java, error-handling, jdbc, e-commerce

Some days ago, I put up [a question here for review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115610/67620) about the best way to handle JDBC transactions in the context of an e-commerce Java web application.

After a kind suggestion from user @gardenhead, I decided to use the `try-with-resources` construct to automatically close my resources, namely the `statement` and the `connection` objects.

I also found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260565/1993790), which told me how to properly use `try-with-resources` for this kind of operation.

This is my improved code:

```
public long insertOrder(Customer customer, Hashtable<String, CartItem> shoppingCart)
{
    try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()) {
         try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            long orderId = System.currentTimeMillis();
            OrderPeer.insertOrder(statement, orderId, customer);
            OrderDetailsPeer.insertOrderDetails(statement, orderId, customer);
            connection.commit();
            return orderId;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection.rollback();
            System.err.println("Could not insert order: " + e.getMessage());
            return 0L;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

The rollback is triggered when either *there is a problem with the transaction itself*, or when *there is a problem with the automatic closing of the statement*. The later due to the fact that it would be indicative of a database access error that left the transaction in an unknown state.

If there is anything else that could be improved, please let me know.

Comment: Do you need to worry about high volumes where you'll be inserting orders with the same `System.currentTimeMillis()` (either multi-threaded writes, or just two instances of your application)?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maps

(copying my answer [from another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105868/24141)):

A `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` (if you require the thread-safety) is preferred over the legacy `Hashtable`, as mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

#### Typo?

```
OrderDetailsPeer.insertOrderDetails(statement, orderId, customer);
```

Compared to your first version, it seems that `shoppingCart` should be inserted here instead of `customer`, unless you have changed your APIs. If so, then `shoppingCart` is *unused* in this method...

Comment: You are right. That was a typo. `shoppingCart` was what I should have written.